# Convention location for JAR files for a LaunchDaemon on OS X?

Tags: mac-osx, hudson, launchd

I'm setting up a [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org) build slave on an OS X machine. I'm using `launchd` to start the slave using the following plist in `/Library/LaunchDaemons/':

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
                       "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>KeepAlive</key>
        <true/>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>org.hudson-ci.jnlpslave</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
                <string>/usr/bin/java</string>
                <string>-jar</string>
                <string>/Users/Shared/Hudson/slave.jar</string>
                <string>-noCertificateCheck</string>
                <string>-jnlpUrl</string>
                <string>file:///Users/Shared/Hudson/slave-agent.jnlp</string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I'm currently putting the `slave.jar` and `slave-agent.jnlp` files in `/Users/Shared/Hudson` but this seems like an unnecessarily user-visible location. What's the convention? Where should I be putting these JARs for a daemon?

Answer (score 1):

Where Do Apps usually write their data? How about the home directory of the user, that the slave runs under?

I have question regarding the slave.jar. Isn't the most current version of the slave.jar downloaded when executing the jnlp file?

Comment: Peter, on OS X, the launchd daemon runs the process, but does not have a home folder. GUI (Cocoa) apps use `/Library/Application Support/[app.bundle.id]/`, but I don't know if this is the best answer for this situation (hence the question).

Comment: `javaws` would download the Jar, but cannot run headless. In this case, we use `java -jar slave.jar -jnlpUrl ...` so that it can run headless.

Comment: A Apple developer page states: "It is also possible to run additional copies of launchd, most often run by a non-root user. When non-root users load jobs, the launchd daemon handling their jobs runs with their non-root privileges, giving an extra layer of security." I would strongly recommend to you not running it under root. So the user that launchd runs under (lets say Hudson) can have a Home directory that is used for all the Hudson files. Work;s like a charm for me. -- see http://developer.apple.com/macosx/launchd.html

Comment: Regarding javaws. You confused me, because you copy the jnlp file, which in your case is completely unnecessary. Did you think about launching the SSL client via SSH? Pros: less configuration issues, slave can be launched on demand, you will always have the newest slave.jar